# webFlux application returns 404 on any request

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-webflux

WebFlux returns 404 on any request, no matter if you are authorized or not.
In my application I'm not using users, but I have tokens, representing their authentication.
If token is valid if give access.

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/token")
public class TokenController {

    @GetMapping("")
    public Mono<ServerResponse> helloWorld() {
        return ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue("Hello world!");
    }

}
```

SecupityConfigure:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(
            ServerHttpSecurity http,
            JwtAuthenticationConverter converter,
            JwtAuthenticationManager manager
    ) {

        AuthenticationWebFilter filter = new AuthenticationWebFilter(manager);

        filter.setServerAuthenticationConverter(converter);

        return http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(
                        (swe, e) ->
                                Mono.fromRunnable(
                                        () -> swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
                                )
                )
                .accessDeniedHandler(
                        (swe, e) ->
                                Mono.fromRunnable(
                                        () -> swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
                                )
                )
                .and()
                    .authorizeExchange()
                        .pathMatchers("api/token*").permitAll()
                    .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilterAt(filter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .build();
    }

}
```

JwtAuthenticationManager, JwtAuthenticationProvider and JwtAuthenticationConverter working fine.

Comment: Any reason to why you are not using the built in JWT functionality that comes with spring security?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration does not have a place where you require authorization nor allow any calls without authorization.

I believe you need to have sections like this:

```
.and()
.authorizeRequests()
```

or/and

```
.antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
.and()
```

in your springSecurityFilterChain.

Please, also consider allowing everything and then adding security configuration step by step.